# Access components c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox

I'm wondering about why can I access text from, for example, a combobox from outside the main class. But I can't add items to it.. **the modifier of my combobox is set to public**

```
public class ImageManager : mainFrame // Where my components are located
{ 
    public ImageManager()
    {

    }

    public void getText()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(comboBox.Text); //Will perfectly retrieve the text from it
    }

    public void setItem()
    {
       comboBox.Items.Add("Items"); //Does absolutely nothing and doesn't show error 
    }
}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: How do you check the content of the combobox?

Comment: In my class mainFrame I set comboBox.Text = "Test" and then when I call getText() from anywhere in ImageManager it show "Test" in my console

Comment: if you try to get the text using comboBox.Text you will get what is displayed in the combobox. if no item is selected you will get nothing until you select an item

Comment: I know that but why can't  I add news items for X reason but I can access text and other features ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your `setItem()` populated a `ComboboxItem` and added it instead of just text?

```
public void setItem() 
{
   ComboboxItem addMe = new ComboboxItem();
   addMe.Text = "your text here";
   addMe.Value = 1234; // make a relevant value
   comboBox.Item.Add(addMe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you got it working, great. But just in case your still scratching your head...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageManager im = new ImageManager();
        im.Show();
        im.setItem();
    }
```

ImageManager inherits from Form2 which has the comboBox. Seemed to work fine. comboBox got populated.